# Regex validator produce migration without changes

Tags: python, django, regex, django-models, django-migrations

Django detect changes in models with RegexValidator,
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

```
url_regex_validator = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^(\w{1,5}:\/\/)([\w\+\/-]+)([\.]\w{1,4})$',
        message="Error invalid URL")
```

model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
path = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True, validators=[url_regex_validator])
```

Every

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> - Alter field path on mymodel

produce a new migration about regex validator in this model. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Django are you on?

Comment: This has been fixed in Django 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25280#no1

A quick fix is to workaround this issue is just copy paste the code in django.core.validators:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
    
    url_regex_validator = [RegexValidator(
            regex=r'^(\w{1,5}:\/\/)([\w\+\/-]+)([\.]\w{1,4})$',
            message="Error invalid URL")]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, validators=url_regex_validator)
```